# Join based on column value

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I'm developing a game which it has a map. In the map, there are several different items like castles (normal players), mines , empty spots and etc which are defined by `type` column . Here's the definition of world:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `world` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `x` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `y` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `coors` (`x`,`y`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1  ;
```

I have other tables like `castles` , `mines`  that I select them, based on value of `type`:

```
foreach($spots as $spot ){
    if($spot['type'] == 1){
        //it's normal castle
            $db->get_castle($spot['id']);
    }else if($spot['type'] == 2){
        //it's a mine
           $db->get_mine($spot['id']);
    }else{
        //empty spot, can be taken by anyone
    }
}
```

Now my question: Is there a way to join different tables based  on `type`'s value?

**Edit:**
definition of `mines`  table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mines` (
  `wid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `castle` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`wid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: What is the composition of `castles` and `mines`? I see no clear foreign key in `world` that would point to an id at another table.

Comment: @TommyCrush `mines` are captured by castles. since `world` table may refer to two tables, I couldn't create a foreign key!

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this that isn't kind of dirty. What you're looking for here is a [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) statement to combine multiple queries. I'm not sure how each table relates to the other, so here is just an example (I'm acting like the x,y coords form some sort of unique identifier in other tables as well. This is dirty enough that you might as well just as a 'foreign_key_id' column and use that for the relation. For mines it will relate to a mine_id and for castles it will relate to a castle_id, etc. It's not proper, but it will work):

```
SELECT 'world'.'x','world'.'y','castle'.'thisfield' AS 'commonName'
FROM 'world'
INNER JOIN 'castle'
ON ('world'.'x' = 'castle'.'x' AND 'world'.'y' = 'castle'.'y')
WHERE 'world'.'type' = '1'

UNION

SELECT 'world'.'x','world'.'y','mines'.'thatfield' AS 'commonName' 
FROM 'world'
INNER JOIN 'mines'
ON ('world'.'x' = 'mines'.'x' AND 'world'.'y' = 'mines'.'y')
WHERE 'world'.'type' = '2';
```

Note that their output is being combined, and thus all selected their column names must be the same (use AS to make that happen).

Comment: Thanks, but `castles` and `mines`  don't have the same number of columns and they may change over time, so union is off the table!

Comment: Then you have no option. Remember you can use empty string in columns to fill the space (SELECT ... '' AS 'columnName')